# Proving $\int_0^{1/x}{\frac{1}{t^2+1}\mathrm{d}t} + \int_0^{x} {\frac{1}{t^2+1}\mathrm{d}t}$ is constant.

Tags: calculus, integration

How does one prove that for $x>0$ 
$$\int_0^{1/x}{\frac{1}{t^2+1}\mathrm{d}t} + \int_0^{x} {\frac{1}{t^2+1}\mathrm{d}t}$$ is equal to a constant?

Comment: Your integrals are incomplete, the closing $dt$ is missing. Then perform a change of variable $t\mapsto 1/t$ in the first integral.

Comment: $$\arctan x+\arctan\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ is pretty trivial, geometrically.

Answer (score 5):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to differentiate the integrals. The second is easy; the first is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{1}{t^2+1}\mathrm{d}t=-\frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{equation*}
It is clear that this will cancel with your result from the second integral. Since the resulting derivative is zero, you must have been dealing with the constant function from the start!

Comment: How did you specifically differentiate the first integral? The 1/x is what's confusing me.

Comment: Oops, mine only works if we assume that $x>0$ (or $x<0$. I forgot the function is not defined at 0!

Comment: You might find this video helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGmVvIglZx8

Comment: Aptly put.  (+1)

Answer (score 4):

We know that $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\arctan\bigl(\frac{1}{x}\bigr)$$
and $$\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\arctan(x)$$
( if you don't know these, use the substitution $t=\tan(u)$ and carry out the integral appropriately )
So, $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}dt+\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\arctan\bigl(\frac{1}{x}\bigr)+\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
To explore why this trig identity is true, let $n=\arctan\bigl(\frac{1}{x}\bigr)$. Then (a rough sketch), $$\implies \tan(n)=\frac{1}{x}\implies x=\cot(n)=\tan\bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}-n\bigr)\implies \arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-n$$ $$\implies \arctan(x)+n=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \arctan(x)+\arctan\bigl(\frac{1}{x}\bigr)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
which is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\color{red}{\int_0^{1/x}{\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt}} +  \int_0^{x} {\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt}&=\color{red}{-\int_{\infty}^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}+\int_0^{x} {\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt}\\
&=\color{red}{\int_x^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}+\int_0^{x} {\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt}\\
&=\color{red}{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}-\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}+\int_0^{x} {\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt}\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}
\end{align}
where the last is free of $x$ and hence is a costant.

Answer (score 0):

Express each integral into sum of two integrals by dividing the interval of integration into two parts. Thus first integral is split as two integrals: one over $[0,1]$ and other over $[1,1/x]$. Call these as $A$ and $B$ respectively. Similarly split the second one into integrals: one over $[0,1]$ and the other over $[1,x]$. Call these $C$ and $D$ respectively. It is now easily seen that $A=C$ and using substitution $t=1/u$ we can show that $B=-D$. So the original sum of two integrals is equal to $$2A=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{t^{2}+1}$$ which is constant (it does not involve any $x$).

A much simpler approach is the one suggested by Lutz in comments to the question but involves the use of improper Riemann integrals which the above approach avoids.